# Cannot create a stored procedure in any db in one instance SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, stored-procedures

Simple generic stored procedure not complicated, could return string or just date and all fail.

```
create procedure get_date
as
select getdate()
```

Error:

> Msg 3616, Level 16, State 2, Procedure get_date, Line 4
>   An error was raised during trigger execution. The batch has been aborted and the user transaction, if any, has been rolled back.

This same error in any db in the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you've got a server-level DDL trigger that's failing somehow. Check for it under Server Objects -> Triggers & see if you can see why it's failing.